# How can I implement process synchronization in Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am new to electron and about to build a mini application.In electron,I have no idea about this situation: main process need to send message to render process A when main process got signal from another render process.
I tried:

```
ipc.on('signalA', function() {
    ipc.sendSync('signalB');
```

});

but it turned out to say sendSync is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

In electron, you can communicate between the main process (main.js) and renderer processes (Browser windows)

main.js :

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 400, height: 275});

win.loadURL(url.format({
   pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
   protocol: 'file:',
   slashes: true
}));

win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
   win.webContents.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping');
});

ipcMain.on('synchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg)  // prints "ping1"
  event.returnValue = 'pong'
});

ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
   console.log(arg)  // prints "ping2"
   event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'pong2');
});
```

In the webpage (index.html):

```
<script>
  const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
  ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
     console.log(arg);  // prints "ping"
     const res = ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-reply', 'ping1');
     console.log(res);  // prints "pong"
  });

  ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping2')
  ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg) // prints "pong2"
  });
</script>
```

you can read the docs here: [ipc-main.md](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md)